# Error in if ((pValue < pFilter) & (coxP < pFilter) & (fiveYearsDiff > : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

```
if((pValue<pFilter) & (coxP<pFilter) & (fiveYearsDiff>0.15)){
         sigGenes=c(sigGenes,gene)
         outTab=rbind(outTab, 
                      cbind(gene=gene,
                            KM=pValue,
                            HR=coxSummary$conf.int[,"exp(coef)"],
                            HR.95L=coxSummary$conf.int[,"lower .95"],
                            HR.95H=coxSummary$conf.int[,"upper .95"],
                            coxPvalue=coxP) )
       }
}
```

I received this error message:

```
Error in if ((pValue < pFilter) & (coxP < pFilter) & (fiveYearsDiff >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

please tell me how to solve this problem,thanks!`enter code here`

Comment: Are all your brackets and commas in the right place?

Comment: YES，the other files can run without error

Comment: Can you print all the values of `pValue`, `pFilter`, `coxP`, `pFilter` and `filveYearsDiff` right before the if statement starts? Are they of the right type?